Do something after succesful login in Rails devise
I have a Rails app and use devise for registration and sign-up of users. Now I want to store the date of the last successful login on the user.
Basically I thought about overwriting the create method  in the session controller but if the password would be wrongly entered it would the store the wrong timestamp. Is there some way of telling rails to call a specific action or block after succesful login? Is there an after_action I can simply add?
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: :create

  def new
    login = I18n.t('header.menu.not_logged_in.login')
    @title = login
    @meta_description = login
    @noindex = true
    super
  end

  def create
    super
  end

  protected

  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource_or_scope)
    set_location_path(resource_or_scope) || stored_location_for(resource_or_scope) || signed_in_root_path(resource_or_scope)
  end

  private

  def set_location_path resource
    if resource&.fitaf_employee?
      admin_root_path
    elsif resource&.non_fitaf_employee?
      if current_user.accounting_company.present?
        home_company_path(company_id: current_user.accounting_company.id, id: current_user.accounting_company.id)
      else
        home_companies_path
      end
    end
  end
end

Do I have to put the code in after_sign_in_path_for in the sessions_controller above? Is there no model I can amend/add?

Devise already does this -- set trackable on the model. https://www.rubydoc.info/github/heartcombo/devise/main/Devise/Models/Trackable

I had to make a migration for users to track certain columns (Google it) + set :trackable on user.rb like described above. After that I had to restart my server for things to work

Almost all the Devise controller actions yield so it's pretty easy to "tap into" the superclass method:
module Users
  class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
    # ...

    def create
      super do |resource|
        # do something with resource
      end
    end
  end
end

In this case it yields after a successful authentication but before the response is set:
class Devise::SessionsController < DeviseController
  # ...

  # POST /resource/sign_in
  def create
    self.resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options)
    set_flash_message!(:notice, :signed_in)
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    yield resource if block_given?
    respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end

  # ...
end

warden.authenticate!(auth_options) will throw if the authentication fails so the yield is not reached in that case.
Also check if Devise doesn't already have the feature you're looking to implement (such as through the Trackable module).

above comment made me look into trackable module which worked! Thanks for explaining the yield thingy!
